# how to set width for a custom lightning component in UI

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system, lightning-components

I have created a custom lightning component, but on the UI it overflows and not able to set the width.
Can anyone please let me know how to do this?

[image: UI of my component]

I need to display this primary contact as other standard lookups, For example in image it should look like pricelist.

My component code looks something like this:

```
<div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">           
                      <lightning:messages />        
                      <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                        <lightning:inputField fieldName="Account__c" value="{!v.quot.Account__c}" required="true"/><!--value="{!v.quot.Account__c}{!v.accId}" -->
                      </div>
                      <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                        <lightning:inputField fieldName="PriceList__c" required="true" value="{!v.quot.PriceList__c}"/> 
                      </div>
                      <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                        <lightning:inputField fieldName="Opportunity__c" value="{!v.recordId}" required="true"/> 
                      </div>
                      <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                        <label class="slds-float_left"><span style="color:red;" align="left">*</span>Primary Contact: </label>
                          <c:customLookup objectAPIName="contact" IconName="standard:contact" selectedRecord="{!v.selectedLookUpRecord}" label="" /> 
                      </div>
                      <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                        <lightning:inputField fieldName="APTS_Quote_Type__c" value="{!v.oppr.OpportunityType__c}"/>
                      </div>
                      <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                        <lightning:inputField fieldName="Selling_Country__c" required="true" value="{!v.quot.Selling_Country__c}"/>
                      </div>
                      <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                        <lightning:inputField fieldName="Order_Type__c" value="{!v.oppr.OpportunityType__c}" required="true"/>
                      </div>
                      <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                        <lightning:inputField fieldName="Old_Owner__c" value="{!v.quot.Old_Owner__c}" readonly="true"/>
                      </div>
                      <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                        <lightning:inputField fieldName="Channel__c" value="{!v.quot.Channel__c}" required="true"/>
                      </div>
                      <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                        <lightning:inputField fieldName="X_code_Backup__c" value="{!v.quot.X_code_Backup__c}" readonly="true"/>
                      </div>
                      <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                        <lightning:inputField fieldName="Xcode__c" value="{!v.quot.Xcode__c}"/>
                      </div>
                      <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                        <lightning:inputField fieldName="X_Code_Account_Backup__c" value="{!v.quot.X_Code_Account_Backup__c}" readonly="true"/>
                      </div>
                      <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                        <lightning:inputField fieldName="Quote_Total1__c" value="{!v.quot.Quote_Total1__c}" readonly="true"/>
                      </div>
                      <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                        <lightning:inputField fieldName="Discount_Exception__c" value="{!v.quot.Discount_Exception__c}"/>
                      </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Can you share the component code?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the Label and lookup component in the same line, I would suggest using flex Box CSS. Please read the [FlexBox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) doc.

The Below code snippet should show labels and components on the same line.

```html
<div style="display:flex; justify-content: space-between ">
  <div> put your label tag </div>
  <div>put your <c:customLookup> component </div>
</div>
```